# How to align/center three divs (icons and text) in footer with three other images (in main-header) with grid? HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, grid

I am relatively new to coding and need help with grid elements. I am re-creating a storefront clothing website for reference. Could someone please help me align/center three divs in my main-footer with three other images in my main section or with the page entirely?
Here is my main-header:

```
<section id="main-headergrid">
        <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="image1">
        <img src="images/image2" alt="image2">
        <img src="images/image3.png" alt="image3">
    </section>
```

Here is my main-footer:

```
<section id="main-footer"> 
    <hr>
    
<div class="icon1">
        <img src="images/icon1.png" alt="icon1" width="150" height="125">
        <h1> icon1 </h1>
        <p> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." </p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon2">
        <img src="images/icon2.png" alt="icon2" width="150" height="125">
        <h1> icon2 </h1>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." </p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon3"> 
        <img src="images/icon3.png" alt="icon3" width="150" height="125">
        <h1> icon3 </h1> 
        <p> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." </p> 
    </div> 
</section>
```

Here is the CSS for them:

```
        
    .container > #main-headergrid { 
        display: flex; 
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
    
        }
    
    
        #main-footer {
            height: 250px; 
            background-color: var(--grey);
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 0px 325px 0px 0px; 
    
        }    
    
        
    
        footer { 
            height: 350px; 
            background-color: #000;
            text-emphasis-color: #FFF;
        
    
        }
```

Comment: Can you Explain what result exactly you are looking. if it's just centering those 3 images in main-headergrid then you can just use `justify-content:center;` in css

Comment: I am trying to create a 3x2 columnxrow grid with the main-header and the main-footer. First off I need to get the text centered with the icons in main-footer. Could I use justify-content for that?

Comment: a 3x3 Grid if you include the text underneath the icons

Comment: you can do that with grid and flex both. use whatever you area comfortable with. do you have a figma or that design which you want to achieve so it made it easy to understand what you want to acieve. I'm assuming that you want to achieve 3x2 columnxrow that you can easily achieve with flexbox and grid too. or you can just use some css framework like tailwind css or bootstrap. too

Answer (score 0):

if you want alignment in 2 dimensions its better to use css grid, and not flexbox
[good resource for css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

flexbox is good if you want vertical or horizontal alignment if you need both look into using css grid.
or you could use margins and padding to manually move elements but would make your page less responsive.

Answer (score 0):

according to what you've stated in comment I guess this is the result you want to achieve. If I misunderstood it then please tell me in comment I will edit the answer according to your need.

```css
#main-headergrid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2rem;
}

#main-footer {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: var(--grey);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top:20px;
  text-align:center;
}

footer {
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #000;
  text-emphasis-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section id="main-headergrid">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa3We.jpg?s=256&g=1" alt="image1">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa3We.jpg?s=256&g=1" alt="image2">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa3We.jpg?s=256&g=1" alt="image3">
</section>

<section id="main-footer">
  <hr>

  <div class="icon1">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa3We.jpg?s=256&g=1" alt="icon1" width="150" height="125">
    <h1> icon1 </h1>
    <p> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." </p>
  </div>
  <div class="icon2">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa3We.jpg?s=256&g=1" alt="icon2" width="150" height="125">
    <h1> icon2 </h1>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." </p>
  </div>
  <div class="icon3">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa3We.jpg?s=256&g=1" alt="icon3" width="150" height="125">
    <h1> icon3 </h1>
    <p> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." </p>
  </div>
</section>
```